# CoreWindow.KeyDown doesn't get called if Enter is pressed with focus on clickable element

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there any way I can still catch the keypress if Enter is pressed on a clickable element.
Because the Windows Store Apps API treats Enter as click event rather than a keypress if the focus is on a clickable element (i.e. a `GridViewItem`).

Unfortunately I have to let the user right-click on a `GridViewItem` which sets the focus to the element.

Moving the focus would be an option but I'd prefer not to do that if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, this is not in the nature of WInrt. You can follow the specification provided on MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown.aspx

You can still try the [Key Down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) event of GridView

Comment: I tried that, but as far as I remember it didn't catch it either.

Answer (score 0):

In WinRT, some events are user-initiated only. As a result, some WinRT APIs can only be invoked in those types of events. Button.Click is one of those events. As a result, you cannot programmatically raise this event because it would undermine the security feature that limits certain API to those types of events.

Make sense?

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense since I'm not trying to raise a click event.
I want to catch an enter keydown but WinRT handles it as click event and doesnt raise a keydown event for the enter press.